# Rails why am i getting undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm trying to create a form where a user can type in their email and it will save it to the db. I want this form in the footer of every page.

I've generated NewsletterSignup via rails scaffolding.

Now i have this code in my /app/views/refinery/_footer.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@newsletter_signup) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and when i try and load the page i get this error:

```
 NoMethodError in Refinery/pages#home

Showing /Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/PersonalTrainingKT/app/views/refinery/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `newsletter_signups_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb84c769ba0>:0x007fb84c08d110>
```

Why is the method undefined? If i run rake routes i can see it exists:

```
newsletter_signups GET    /newsletter_signups(.:format)          newsletter_signups#index
                       POST   /newsletter_signups(.:format)          newsletter_signups#create
 new_newsletter_signup GET    /newsletter_signups/new(.:format)      newsletter_signups#new
edit_newsletter_signup GET    /newsletter_signups/:id/edit(.:format) newsletter_signups#edit
     newsletter_signup GET    /newsletter_signups/:id(.:format)      newsletter_signups#show
                       PUT    /newsletter_signups/:id(.:format)      newsletter_signups#update
                       DELETE /newsletter_signups/:id(.:format)      newsletter_signups#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
PersonalTrainingKT::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :newsletter_signups

  # This line mounts Refinery's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to the root URL of your application will go to Refinery::PagesController#home.
  # If you would like to change where this extension is mounted, simply change the :at option to something different.
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
end
```

I'm also creating a new object in the application_controller since this newsletter signup will be available on every page:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :instantiate_newsletter_signup

  def instantiate_newsletter_signup
    @newsletter_signup = NewsletterSignup.new
  end
end
```

Comment: i've posted my routes except for the refinerycms routes - of which there are a ton of those.

Comment: I think all i need to do is make the form_for look specifically to my newsletter_signups_controller right?

Comment: @ctcherry I've posted my routes.rb file now.

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, you have restarted the web server since running the scaffold generator?

Comment: It looks right, I'm not sure why it's not picking up the route. Have you tried specifying the url directly: form_for(@newsletter_signup, :url => newsletter_signups_path, :method => :post)?

Comment: If i do that i get the same thing basically - "undefined local variable or method `newsletter_signups_path'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like since refinerycms mounts the routes (not sure if that's correct terminology), it cannot see normal routes.

From this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/refinery-cms/5k7Co4D1bVI I figured out that i needed to change

```
<%= form_for(@newsletter_signup, :url => newsletter_signups_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for(@newsletter_signup, :url => main_app.newsletter_signups_path, :method => :post) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Nice one, glad you got it sorted :)

Comment: Nice work! That was a bit outside of normal Rails conventions

Comment: Actually it's normal Rails conventions for mounted engines like Refinery is.

Comment: I want to give you +1000000000000